# custom helpers inside each block

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

```
myArray = [{name: "name1", age: 20}, {name: "name2", age:22}];

{{#each person in myArray}}
  {{#myHelper person}}
    Do something
  {{/myHelper}}
{{/each}}

Handlebars.registerHelper(function(context, options){ 
 if(context.age > 18){
   return options.fn(this);
 }else{
   return options.inverse(this);
 }
})
```

In the above code when I tried to debug my custom helper it shows the `context="person"` while I want the `context` to be the `person` object, what's wrong with my code ?

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368433/how-to-implement-nested-each-loops-with-custom-helpers-handlebar) but did not get it either...

Comment: Is Ember's Handlebars not really Handlebars at all? `{{#each a in b}}` is not Handlebars at all but apparently Handlebars-inside-Ember is okay with it. Bizarre.

Comment: @muistooshort Ember uses the same handlebars build, but it adds a few more helpers.. I believe the problem here is the `registerHelper` function that's missing the name (i think yours was correct tho). I think the code above is just an abstract code to who what he wants.

Comment: Unspecified, take a look at eviltrout's commit for the unbound block. It might be what you're looking for in regards to defining/using custom helpers. [Link to GitHub](https://github.com/eviltrout/ember.js/commit/6ad634b92d7d000ca42c0876800c6f7e24cba96b)

Comment: I think what you want is a bound helper. This question seems like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837958/writing-a-helper-that-produces-bound-results where @Jo liss gave a good workaround until https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1274 is merged

Comment: So I need to bind the path in order to use it ? I mean the same helper if not in each block would just work fine...